# Unable to use Matplotlib - Ubuntu 10.10 and Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am running python3.2 on Ubuntu 10.10 i386 (32 bit).

I just installed [matplotlib-py3](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3) (from source) for learning purposes and when I try one of the many examples on the website:

```
##!/usr/local/bin/python3.2
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
```

In the terminal I get a lot of errors when it's importing matplotlib:

```
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 16, in <module>
    import matplotlib.axis as maxis
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as mtext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import RendererBase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 47, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 60, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried with a couple of examples from the website and they all give the same errors. When I `import  matplotlib` by itself in the interactive python shell everything works fine, it's only when I import things like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` that I see all these errors.

Don't know if I installed it the wrong way or if I'm doing something wrong, but that's why I'm posting here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your libpng is not installed correctly. It's hard to say exactly what is wrong, but either you haven't installed those libraries or it's development headers (but I suspect that matplotlib installation then would have failed), or perhaps matplotlib assumes certain locations for the libraries. They moved in Ubuntu 10.10. to allow for 32 and 64 bit libraries on the same machine, so if matplotlib assumes a certain location that would fail on 10.10.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know. Worst case scenario would be to use my windows XP machine..which is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Install the libpng without apt-get

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.5.4.tar.gz?download
tar xzf libpng-1.5.4.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
```

or

```
./configure

make
sudo make install
```

Comment: If you have also problem, ```sudo ldconfig```